# Images Slider displaying incorrectly after cached

Tags: javascript, html, css, http, cross-browser

I'm developing a simple website which must have an images slider on the index.
I got a code from the Internet which example does exactly what I want.

The problem appeared when I applied it to my page. I noticed that when the page is cached, images are displayed one under the other, instead of keep in the slider. Like this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjimenezg/2wjy400o/)

I'm using XAMPP (so Apache) but I don't know yet what am I going to use when the webpage is launched, because we have not decided the domain.

I found a solution which works for Google Chrome, as simple as adding

```
<?php header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); ?>
```

to the header. The problem is that IE and Firefox seem not to accept this...

Some suggestion please? Thank you very much.

EDIT: Adding the Cache-Control works for Chrome in my localhost, but it doesn't in my temp domain ([canterasriomino.site90.com](http://canterasriomino.site90.com)). I don't know what to do.

**EDIT2: Ok, the problem now is on the scripts because it only breaks up when clicking on menu buttons (which use jquery to update "maincont" content... Some suggestion? Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution a long time ago, whether it helps here I wouldn't know, whenever i import i script i add the time to the end

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

becomes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js?<?=time()?>"></script>
```

adding the time will stop the page caching the file, I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your help. Anyway it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry about that, just to check have you made sure to clear your cache?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. First time usually shows correctly, but it seems to save a cached copy and then it is when showed wrong. That's why I want to get a way of avoiding cache

Comment: Are you using img tags to load the images? if so use what i showed you because that is never cached.